# Reset not working in dom level- ng-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

I'm using ng-multiselect-dropdown in my angular 7 project.I want to reset dropdown values, so i using below method,but only stored values cleared in variable ; dom values not cleared in my template.And i need validations also.Kindly help me.

```js
resetSelection() {
  this.selectedTestCompounds = [];        
}

<ng-multiselect-dropdown  
  id="testSample"
  [placeholder]="'select'"
  [data]="sampleList"                                                 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedTestCompounds"                                 
  [settings]="dropdownSettingsTestCompound"                           
  (onSelect)="onItemSelectTestCompound($event)"                       
  (onSelectAll)="onSelectAllTestCompound($event)"
  >
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
<button (click)="resetSelection()" >clear</button>
```

Comment: It should work fine.. Can I see your code for `dropdownSettingsTestCompound`?

Comment: In ng-multiselect-dropdown, it has setting which contains clearSearchFilter. clearSearchFilter is of type boolean which clear search filter. You can make that true on resetSelection(), Hope it will work.

Comment: I have already tried.//Multiple Select dropdown settings(Compound)
        this.dropdownSettingsCompound = {
            singleSelection: false,
            idField: 'id',
            textField: 'code',
            selectAllText: 'All',
            unSelectAllText: 'All',
            itemsShowLimit: 10,
            allowSearchFilter: true
        };

Comment: @wentjun,this.dropdownSettingsCompound = { singleSelection: false, idField: 'id', textField: 'code', selectAllText: 'All', unSelectAllText: 'All', itemsShowLimit: 10, allowSearchFilter: true };

Comment: @Saniyasyedqureshi, I want to clear ngModule value in dropdown list.not search value.

Comment: @Muthukumar did you ever find a solution?